# bower fails with 'ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.spacefiles'

Tags: bower, bower-install

Bower install seems to be consistently failing for multiple packages for me. I've tried removing the below (nestable) package mention and it then fails for others.

I've tried setting the git settings -

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

but still fails. I've even tried to point the nestable package to the correct github repo, but still fails. Same keeps happening for some other packages also, not for all packages though.

```
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects:  20% (1/5)
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects:  40% (2/5)
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects:  60% (3/5)
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects:  80% (4/5)
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5)
bower progress      nestable#* remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
bower invalid-meta  nestable is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower invalid-meta  nestable is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower resolved      git://github.com/dbushell/Nestable.git#4f93032cfa
bower ENOTFOUND     getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.spacefiles

Stack trace:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.spacefiles
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
From previous event:
    at UrlResolver.Resolver.resolve (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\bower\lib\core\resolvers\Resolver.js:100:6)
    at PackageRepository._resolve (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\bower\lib\core\PackageRepository.js:175:21)
    at C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\core\Package
Repository.js:77:29

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:82:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bo
wer\bin\bower:110:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Logger.emit (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\nod
e_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\ind
ex.js:45:20
    at _rejected (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_
modules\q\q.js:844:24)
    at C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q
.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\no
de_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
    at C:\Users\DevAdmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q
.js:604:44
System info:
Bower version: 1.4.1
Node version: 0.12.6
OS: Windows_NT 6.3.9600 x64
```

Below is the bower.json

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "@clo"
  ],
  "description": "Demo",
  "main": "index.html",
  "keywords": [
    "bootstrap",
    "angular",
    "admin",
    "theme",
    "dashboard"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "Flot": "flot/flot#0.8.3",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.7.0",
    "angular-translate": "2.6.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
    "angular": "1.3.13",
    "angular-i18n": "1.3.13",
    "angular-route": "1.3.13",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.1",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.13",
    "angular-translate-loader-url": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.6.0",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.13",
    "angular-ui-utils": "0.2.2",
    "angularjs-toaster": "0.4.8",
    "flatdoc": "0.9.0",
    "fontawesome": "4.2.0",
    "oclazyload": "0.5.2",
    "screenfull": "2.0.0",
    "slimScroll": "1.3.3",
    "weather-icons": "1.3.2",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "chosen_v1.2.0": "https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.2.0/chosen_v1.2.0.zip",
    "flot-spline": "*",
    "flot.tooltip": "0.8.4",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.3",
    "jqueryui-touch-punch": "*",
    "seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "4.5.0",
    "jquery.inputmask": "3.1.61",
    "bootstrap-wysiwyg": "*",
    "ika.jvectormap": "*",
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "fullcalendar": "2.2.7",
    "animate.css": "3.2.1",
    "fastclick": "1.0.6",
    "modernizr": "2.8.3",
    "animo.js": "ThrivingKings/animo.js#1.0.2",
    "jquery-classyloader": "http://www.class.pm/files/jquery-classyloader.zip",
    "whirl": "1.0.0",
    "skycons": "darkskyapp/skycons",
    "jQuery-gMap": "marioestrada/jQuery-gMap#2.1.5",
    "ngDialog": "0.3.11",
    "codemirror": "5.0.0",
    "marked": "0.3.3",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.4.2",
    "ngWig": "stevermeister/ngWig#0.8.5",
    "bootstrap-filestyle": "1.1.2",
    "parsleyjs": "2.0.7",
    "datatables": "1.10.5",
    "datatables-colvis": "1.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.13",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.13",
    "angular-chosen-localytics": "1.0.6",
    "ng-table": "0.5.1",
    "ng-table-export": "*",
    "simple-line-icons": "0.1.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-nav-tree": "*",
    "nestable": "*",
    "html.sortable": "0.1.8",
    "angular-xeditable": "0.1.8",
    "angular-file-upload": "1.1.5",
    "ng-img-crop": "0.3.2",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.9.6",
    "angular-ui-codemirror": "0.2.2",
    "angular-carousel": "0.3.10",
    "angular-touch": "1.3.13",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.27",
    "ng-grid": "2.0.14",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.0",
    "Chart.js": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.3",
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "fullcalendar": "2.2.7",
    "angular": "1.3.13",
    "weather-icons": "1.3.2",
    "jquery.inputmask": "3.1.61",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.13",
    "angular-translate": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.6.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.7.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-url": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.6.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.6.0",
    "angular-ui-utils": "0.2.2",
    "flatdoc": "0.9.0",
    "screenfull": "2.0.0",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "4.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.2.1",
    "fastclick": "1.0.6",
    "ngDialog": "0.3.11",
    "codemirror": "5.0.0",
    "marked": "0.3.3",
    "parsleyjs": "2.0.7",
    "datatables": "1.10.5",
    "ng-table": "0.5.1"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Am seeing that its failing randomly for packages

```
    bower resolved      git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n.git#1.3.13
bower resolved      git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.2.0
bower ENOTFOUND     getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.spacefiles

Stack trace:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.spacefiles
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

And if I try to do a manual install of the individual package that seems to fail, it succeeds for that.

What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, It's from your `bower.json` file.
In my case, the source URL is no more in use. I purchased a theme from here [theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/angle-bootstrap-admin-template-WB04HF123)

So there is one dependency from the URL

```
"jquery-classyloader": "https://vox.space/file_download/24/jquery-classyloader.zip"
```

Surprisely **vox.space** is no more alive, So every time I got `ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vox.space vox.space`

You also need to validate the existence of some dependency in your code and remove it if not necessary.